# IndexOutOfRangeException при работе с PSB файлом. Unity2d

Tags: unity3d, photoshop

После перенесения картинки в формате psb в Unity, последняя выдает

```
IndexOutOfRangeException:
Index was outside the bounds of the array.PhotoshopFile.Compression.ZipPredict32Image.Unpredict (System.Byte[] ptrData, System.Byte[] ptrOutput) 
(at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.2d.psdimporter@1.0.0-preview.4/Editor/PSDPlugin/PsdFile/Compression/ZipPredict32Image.cs:175).
```

- PSB Importer установлен.
- Версия Unity - 2018.4.36f1 Personal.
- Версия Photoshop - 2015.

В качестве подготовительных действий только установил PSB Importer

Comment: это полный ппц, в версии 2018 года почему то не показывается psb файл. Установил 2020  - сразу все заработало

Comment: Не занимайтесь херней. не должно быть в играх никаких psb, это бред.